# photoelectric emission with multiple photons

Tags: photoelectric-effect

Is it possible for two or more photons to collide simultaneously with one electron, resulting in the emission of that electron from the metal surface? I searched for two photon absorption and found that an atom or molecule can absorb two photons if the sum of their energies is greater than the work function, but I want to know whether it is possible for two or more photons to interact with a single **electron** and cause its emission?

Comment: It is possible. In general the first photon's stimulation would raise the electron to some quasi-stable state which has a lifetime long enough to allow the second photon's stimulation to supply the necessary energy for ejection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Photoelectric Effect, Why can't two quanta interact with an electron at the same time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95411/)